# How do I take the values of a Radio Button to a new page, after i have checked if they are correct?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function

I am making a questionnaire and am not brilliant with JS. I want to take the results of the radio buttons which have been marked, so either True or False, and then show them on another page. I have the questions in a form.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling/style.css">
    <title>1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

        function sendclick() {
            var answers = [document.forms["questionarre"]["clickRule"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["404error"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["colour"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["H2Tag"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["SiteMap"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["heading"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["alttag"].value,
                document.forms["questionarre"]["UseAgain"].value];
            var count = 0
            for (var i = 0; i<answers.length; i++) {
                if (answers[i] == "") {
                    var temp = i+1;
                    alert("Please complete question "+temp);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }

            if (count == answers.length) { 
                var correct = [document.getElementById("correct1").checked,
                document.getElementById("correct2").checked,
                document.getElementById("correct3").checked,
                document.getElementById("correct4").checked,
                document.getElementById("correct5").checked,
                document.getElementById("correct6").checked];
                //window.open("YourResults.html", "_self")  
            }
        }
    /*
        for (var i = 0; i<x.length; i++) {
                if (x[i] == "") {
                    var temp = i+1;
                    //  alert("results"+x)//window.open("results"+x);
                    break;}
            }

        }function - sendClick end

        function opener() {
            var text = document.getElementById('correct7').value;
            var target = {
            non text content : alert("correct")
            };
            if (text in targetNames) {
                window.open(targetNames[text]);  
            }
        }

            document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', opener, false);
*/
    </script>

    <div id="questionarre_bg">
    <form name="questionarre" action=""  method="post">
        <div id="Question1">
            <p class="thicker">How many clicks do developers use to keep the user close to information? </p>
            <input type="radio" name="clickRule" value=1>1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="clickRule" value=4>4
            <input type="radio" name="clickRule" id="correct1" value=3>3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="clickRule" value=6>6
        </div>

        <div id="Question2">
            <p class="thicker">How are developers using the 404 Error Page, for keep the users happy?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="404error"  id="correct2" value="Including links">Including links<br>
            <input type="radio" name="404error" value="displaying a video">displaying a video<br>
            <input type="radio" name="404error" value="playing music">playing music<br>
        </div>

        <div id="Question3">
            <p class="thicker">Should you rely on colour alone in a website build?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Yes">Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" name="colour" id="correct3" value="No">No
        </div>

        <div id="Question4">
            <p class="thicker">A H2 Tag is useful for?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="H2Tag" id="correct4" value="The disabled autoreaders">The disabled autoreaders<br>
            <input type="radio" name="H2Tag" value="Pretty webpages">Pretty webpages<br> 

        </div>


        <div id="Question5">
            <p class="thicker" >What is correct name given to page of the websites pages?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="SiteMap" value="Tube Map">Tube Map
            <input type="radio" name="SiteMap" id="correct5" value="Site Map">Site Map <br>
            <input type="radio" name="SiteMap" value="Map">Map
            <input type="radio" name="SiteMap" value="Page List">Page List
        </div>

        <div id="Question6">
            <p class="thicker">A webpage heading should do what?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="heading" id="correct6" value="Tell the user about the content in a few words">Tell the user about the content in a few words<br>
            <input type="radio" name="heading" value="include meaningless text">include meaningless text<br>
            <input type="radio" name="heading" value="Be short">Be short<br>
        </div>

        <div id="Question7">
            <p class="thicker">The Alt tag is used for what....</p>
            <input type="text" name="alttag" id="correct7" ><br><!--ANSWER__non text content--> 
        </div>

        <div id="Question8">
            <p class="thicker">Would you use this website again for information?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="UseAgain" value="Yes">Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" name="UseAgain" value="No">No<br>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>
        </form>

        <button onclick="sendclick()">send</button>


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about _submitting_ the form …? That’s their purpose, after all.

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the answer through local storage 
it would be something like this

```js
//save the info on page 1
//resultArr will be the array holding all the radio results, 
//you could get them by jQuery or any other method to you are comfortable with

localStorage.setItem("answers", answers);
// Retrieve the info on page 2
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("answers")[0];
```

you can read more about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp